# Passing multiple params and multiple functions into a function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, composition

I have a function

```
 await mainFunction(function1, function2, function3)
```

I also want to pass multiple functions into the mainFunction

```
const mainFunction =   async (function1, function2, function3) =>  async ({ param1, param2, param3}) => {

const params = { param1, param3, param3};
```

How do I do this without passing it as another param?

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: if you call mainFunction first with required function args, you can call the resulting function with params. `await(await mainFunction(...<functions>)(params)`

Comment: but yea, question's not that clear, if you can double check it and explain a bit better would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to pass indefinite number of arguments to your main function, so you can use the `...rest` parameter.

> The rest parameter syntax allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an **array**, providing a way to represent variadic functions in JavaScript. *(from MDN)*

**Note.** You can call the `rest parameter` whatever you want.

So in your code it will look something like this:

```js
const mainFunction = async (...functions) => {
  // DO SOMETHING WITH THE PARAMS ARRAY
}
```

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 0):

if you want to maintain your current syntax you can do it like this

```js
const mainFunction = (function1, function2, function3) => async ({ param1, param2, param3 }) => {
  const params = { param1, param2, param3 };
  console.log(params);
  await function1(param1);
  await function2(param2);
  await function3(param3);
};

const function1 = (param) => console.log('function1', param);
const function2 = (param) => console.log('function2', param);
const function3 = (param) => console.log('function3', param);

const paramsObject = {
  param1: 'Value 1',
  param2: 'Value 2',
  param3: 'Value 3',
};

const innerFunction = mainFunction(function1, function2, function3);
innerFunction(paramsObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the spread operator `...` to pass a variadic number of arguments to your fuction like this

```js
const mainFunction = (...functions) => (args) => Promise.all(functions.map(f => f(args)))

const args = {
  param1: {
    test: 1
  },
  param2: {
    test: 2
  },
  param3: {
    test: 3
  }
}

const f1 = ({param1}) => Promise.resolve({...param1})
const f2 = ({param2}) => Promise.resolve({...param2})
const f3 = (args) => Promise.resolve({...args})

mainFunction(f1, f2, f3)(args).then(console.log)
```